# Overlapping timeframes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following rows in my table:

```
Customer  Start       End
1A        2019-01-01  2019-01-04
1A        2019-01-03  2019-01-06
1A        2019-01-06  2019-01-10
1A        2019-02-01  2019-02-07
2A        2019-03-01  2019-04-05
```

I need to consolidate the table to look like this:

```
Customer  Start       End
1A        2019-01-01  2019-01-10
1A        2019-02-01  2019-02-07
2A        2019-03-01  2019-04-05
```

What are some steps that I can take in SQL which would let me achieve this?

Comment: You could group by year and month, then take min(start) and max(end)

Comment: Please tell more about algorithm, how it should be done? If periods overlaps per customer then them should be grouped?

Comment: This is basically a gaps-and-islands problem. Check out [my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025748/date-range-with-minimum-and-maximum-dates-from-dataset-having-records-with-conti/49026077#49026077) for details.

Comment: Itzik Ben-Gan shows several approaches in his article [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/). You'd better clarify in the question whether `Start` and `End` are inclusive or not. And what result would you like to see if you have touching intervals like `3A, '2019-01-03', '2019-01-06'` and `3A, '2019-01-07', '2019-01-10'`

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  You are trying to combine periods.  One method to find overlaps uses a cumulative `max()`.  Then use this to identify groups.  And finally use aggregation:

```
select customer, min(start), max(end)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_max >= start then 0 else 1 end) over  -- beginning of a new period
                  (partition by customer order by start) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end) over (partition by customer
                                  order by start
                                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                 ) as prev_max_end
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by customer, grp;
```

Note that both `start` and `end` as SQL Server reserved words, so they are very bad names for columns.  I haven't renamed them or escaped them, assuming that your actual columns have more appropriate names.

Comment: Itzik Ben-Gan shows several approaches in his article [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `DATEPART(MONTH, DATE)` and `MIN()`, `MAX()` aggregate window function you can achieve your expected result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer, 
       MIN(Start) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, StartMonth) AS Start,
       MAX([End]) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, EndMonth) AS [End]
FROM (
    SELECT *, DATEPART(MONTH, Start) AS StartMonth, DATEPART(MONTH, [End]) AS EndMonth
    FROM TestTable
) Q
```

Please find the working demo on [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b637da530b7f257f2018b34d26474fb1).

Sample execution with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Customer VARCHAR(2), Start DATE, [End] DATE);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Customer, Start, [End]) VALUES
('1A', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-04'),
('1A', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-06'),
('1A', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-10'),
('1A', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-07'),
('2A', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-05');

SELECT DISTINCT Customer, 
       MIN(Start) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, StartMonth) AS Start,
       MAX([End]) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, EndMonth) AS [End]
FROM (
    SELECT *, DATEPART(MONTH, Start) AS StartMonth, DATEPART(MONTH, [End]) AS EndMonth
    FROM @TestTable
) Q
```

Comment: I think that he wants, to group periods which overlaps. Not to take the min and max for each month.

Comment: That's correct @lypskee, I can't take the min and max only because there could be more than two events in one single month that are not necessarily a day apart

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group by as well. Going forward if you are storing more than one year you will have to account for that too. Try this

```
 DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Customer VARCHAR(2), Start DATE, [End] DATE);

 INSERT INTO @TestTable (Customer, Start, [End]) VALUES
 ('1A', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-04'),
 ('1A', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-06'),
 ('1A', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-10'),
 ('1A', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-07'),
 ('2A', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-05'),
 ('1A', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-07'),
 ('2A', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-05');

 SELECT Customer, MIN(Start), MAX([End]) FROM @TestTable
 GROUP By Customer, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Start), 0) , 
 DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [End]), 0)
```