# Minimum and maximum dates within continuous date range grouped by name

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a data ranges with start and end date for a persons, I want to get the continuous date ranges only per persons:

Input:

```
NAME | STARTDATE      | END DATE
--------------------------------------
MIKE | **2019-05-15** | 2019-05-16 
MIKE | 2019-05-17     | **2019-05-18**
MIKE | 2020-05-18     | 2020-05-19
```

Expected output like:

```
MIKE | **2019-05-15** | **2019-05-18** 
MIKE | 2020-05-18     | 2020-05-19
```

So basically output is MIN and MAX for each continuous period for the person.

Appreciate any help.

I have tried the below query:

```
With N AS (   SELECT Name, StartDate, EndDate
       , LastStop = MAX(EndDate) 
                    OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate 
                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)   FROM   Table  ), B AS (   SELECT Name, StartDate, EndDate
       , Block = SUM(CASE WHEN LastStop Is Null Then 1
                          WHEN LastStop < StartDate Then 1
                          ELSE 0
                    END)
                 OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY StartDate, LastStop)   FROM   N ) SELECT Name
     , MIN(StartDate) DateFrom
     , MAX(EndDate) DateTo FROM   B GROUP BY Name, Block ORDER BY Name, Block
```

But its not considering the continuous period. It's showing the same input.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025748/date-range-with-minimum-and-maximum-dates-from-dataset-having-records-with-conti

Comment: Add what you tried to your question.

Comment: but not considering continuous period .. it will show min and max only ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using an ad-hoc tally table

**Example  or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9f097b9058f61ba7e9b443d9b935c8d6)**

```
;with cte as (
Select A.[Name]
      ,B.D
      ,Grp  = datediff(day,'1900-01-01',D) - dense_rank() over (partition by [Name] Order by D)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,StartDate,EndDate)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),StartDate) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2 
             ) B

)
Select [Name]
      ,StartDate= min(D)
      ,EndDate  = max(D)
 From  cte
 Group By [Name],Grp
```

**Returns**

```
Name    StartDate   EndDate
MIKE    2019-05-15  2019-05-18
MIKE    2020-05-18  2020-05-19
```

**Just to help with the Visualization, the CTE generates the following**

[image]

Comment: i tried to change the last data row like this: ,('MIKE','2019-05-18','2019-05-19')...in the case the results should be: MIKE 2019-05-15 2019-05-19

Comment: @Basharal I see in your dbFiddle, you have overlapping records/dates.   Change row_number to dense_rank

Comment: @Basharal  Updated dbFiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7e1c921678272c3309476c79008a2df9

Comment: @Basharal Updated my answer with dense_rank()

Comment: Great ! ..Thanks A lot @John .. it worked perfectly now.

Comment: @Basharal Always happy to help.

Comment: Thanks..if you don't mind to explain What is the purpose of system table  master..spt_value ?

Comment: @Basharal Actually any table of appropriate size will do.   I use these to generate an ad-hoc numbers/tally table.    If  you have a numbers table or even a calendar table, they can be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a type of gap-and-islands problem.  There is no need to expand the data out by day!  That seems very inefficient.

Instead, determine the "islands".  This is where there is no overlap -- in your case `lag()` is sufficient.  Then a cumulative sum and aggregation:

```
select name, min(startdate), max(enddate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_enddate >= dateadd(day, -1, startdate) then 0 else 1 end) over 
                 (partition by name order by startdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(enddate) over (partition by name order by startdate) as prev_enddate
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by name, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d2885665a24e3a9de5ce33490dcf48bd) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. it's working perfect and yes exactly.. actually in my case i am dealing with BiG data with thousands with records.. so am looking for an efficient way as well...

Comment: Actually the script will not work if i switched the order of the data like this case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=aa2de3d18e4d18399d2237a2703bb863

Comment: @Basharal . . . You might want to ask a new question.  But as I read the Fiddle, the rows should be combined because they overlap.  If there is some other reason, then include that in a new question.

Comment: @Basharal . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  Not only does it work, but it doesn't use any "special" external table, so it works regardless of the size of the groups.  And it doesn't multiply out the rows to define the groups.

Comment: @Grodon... I agree with you.. but because in my case the data is not ordered .. example i the fiddle i sent before... so the other answer works for me no matter the data is ordered in the DB.. it should return the expected results...so this is why.. appreciate your help.

Comment: @Basharal . . . This answer does not depend on the ordering of the data.  Tables are not ordered, so SQL queries cannot be affect by something that doesn't exist.  I even provided a db<>fiddle that shows this working.

Answer (score 0):

This  will give you the same result

```
    SELECT subquery.name,min(subquery.startdate),max(subquery.enddate1)
FROM (SELECT NAME,startdate,
      CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT yt1.startdate 
                       FROM t yt1 
                       WHERE yt1.startdate = DATEADD(day, 1, yt2.enddate) 
                       ) THEN null else yt2.enddate END as enddate1
      FROM t yt2) as subquery
GROUP by NAME, CAST(MONTH(subquery.startdate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(subquery.startdate) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

For the `CASE WHEN EXISTS`  I refered to [SQL CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

For the group by month and year you can see this [GROUP BY MONTH AND YEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406170/sql-grouping-by-month-and-year)

[DB_FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=20b73ac98e5c6d91aa47924802385009)

Comment: @Basharal FYI I suggest not referring to people on this site as "dear" - many people would find it weird.